# Resizable ggplot images in flexdashboard?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown

By default, `flexdashboard` displays all images using the same predefined size.

Hence, I want to be able to do the following two things:

1. be able to display the image so it occupies the full availale space (maximize it), and / or
2. be able to allow a user to modify image size interactively using shiny sliders.

Is that possible to do? At least the first of these tasks, which seems easier.

Below is the .Rmd code and the screenshot of what it does now. You'll note the image is cut at the bottom and I don't know how to change its size.

[image]

````
---
title: "Resizable ggplot images in flexdashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  vertical_layout: fill 
  orientation: columns
runtime: shiny
---

 ## Left column ----

This dashboard shows how you can resize ggplot images  in 'flexdashboard'.

## Right column, where the shiny sliders and image are displayed --- 

  ```{r}
library(ggplot2)
# fluidPage(  # This does not help
  fluidRow( 
    column(width=4, checkboxInput("maximize_image", "Maximize image",  T) ),
    column(width=4, sliderInput("image_width", "Image width", 2, 6, 3) ), 
    column(width=4, sliderInput("image_height", "Image height ", 2, 9, 4) )
  )
  renderPlot( 
    ggplot(pressure) + geom_point (aes(temperature,pressure))
  )
# )


 # end of .Rmd code
````

Comment: I've looked at the help for  fillPage, fillCol /  fillRow functions, which supposedly should help to resize the plotted area. Maybe someting like `fillPage(
  fillCol(
    div(style = "background-color: red; width: 100%; height: 100%;",
     renderPlot( ggplot(pressure) + geom_point (aes(temperature,pressure)) ) )
  )
)` could help, were the width can be changed via 'input$image_width'?

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to do the trick:

```
library(ggplot2)

fluidRow( 
  # column(width=4, checkboxInput("maximize_image", "Maximize image",  T) ),
  column(width=4, sliderInput("image_width", "Image width", 50, 100, 50) ), 
  column(width=4, sliderInput("image_height", "Image height ", 50, 100, 50 ) ),
)

renderUI(
  fillPage(
    div(style = paste0("width: ", input$image_width, "%;", " height: ", input$image_height, "%;"),
        renderPlot( ggplot(pressure) + geom_point (aes(temperature,pressure)) ) )
  )
)
```

It's probably not the best (as it does not know the maximum *visible* space, so you have to manually play with slider to find out that height=87% is the one you are looking for.

Still though, I'm surprised I could not find it anywhere, because it seems super-handy.

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, changing this does not make any difference  ` vertical_layout:  scroll #fill `

Comment: Critically, you have to include this r code in `###` section. It will not work if have in `##` or at the `####` section